# Run SSIS package through Server its working fine but that package I am running on my local system its not working

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2022

I am using SSMS 2016 client and Visual Studio 2017 on my local system.

I created a package in Visual Studio 2017, this package is based on package deployment model, I'm running this package through PowerShell and call the execute package utility it present in this location

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn
```

It's working.

But I'm using my existing package who build in Visual Studio 2017 (2 years ago) it was run on server properly but it is not running on my local system.

I'm using Execute package utility to run this package, I get an error:

> Error Code :- 0xC000F427
>
> Error :- To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.

I do no why its giving me a error I am searching every where no one can giving me the answer no other website posted this answer.

After that I was installed SSMS 2022 [SQL2022-SSEI-Dev.exe] and I am doing a setup by my own

My packages was worked properly and run by Execute package utility also .

Now I have a doubt in SSMS 2016.

I have created my own package it was works properly on my system but why not existing package will work?

In this particular situation Execute package utility will not worked for both the packages but why its works for one and not for another one?

I want running my both ssis packages by Execute package utility and which point I missed??

Comment: Execute package utility it only works on ssms server not client??

Comment: The path 130 is the version.  See following for compatibility https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html